# Is there GSSAPI encryption support in pg/pgx libraries?

Tags: postgresql, go, kerberos

So I am trying to connect to postgres in golang using GSSAPI (kerberos). Currently I am using pgx library along with gopgkrb5. I am successfully connecting and authenticating with gssapi, the only problem is - connection is not secure. When I edit **pg_hba.conf** to accept only secure gssapi connections, It does not work (no entry found for insecure connection). I read that postgres supports GSSAPI encryption, but It seems like pgx(pgconn in particular) does not support it. Am I wrong? Or, if not, does pq support it?

Comment: Does the library link with libpq? If yes, it needs to be a recent enough version of libpq.

Comment: you mean C's library? As far as I know, it does not use c bindings

Comment: Run an `ldd` on the pgx library to see.

Comment: pgx does not use libpg, it just implements the wire protocol without external deps. Afaik there is no support for GSSAPI in pgx. However there was/is support in https://github.com/lib/pq which is considered not maintained any more.